# Sorting a Name Array by Last Name?

Tags: regex, perl, sorting

Given an array of name scalars ("Joe Hanson", "James Rutherford McCoy", "Thomas Jay Samuels", etc...) how do I sort them by last name?

I'm a bit new to Perl (and scripting languages in general) and can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: How will you sort *José Ortega y Gasset*?

Comment: So you want to process names? – Hah! Read [“*Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names*”](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) and despair … correctly handling names is *incredibly* complex (in a sense, even harder than correctly handling datetimes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a job for the Schwartzian Transform (assuming as others have that the last string is the last name):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @names = ( 'Joe Hanson', 'James Rutherford McCoy', 'Thomas Jay Samuels', 'Joe Johnson', 'Tim McGee', 'The Reverend Horton Heat');

my @sorted_names = 
    map { $_->[0] }
    sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] }
    map { [$_, /(\w+)$/] } @names;

print "$_\n" for @sorted_names;
```

Running this will result in:

```
Joe Hanson
The Reverend Horton Heat
Joe Johnson
James Rutherford McCoy
Tim McGee
Thomas Jay Samuels
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => qw/all/;
use Data::Dumper;

my @names = ("Joe Hanson", "James Rutherford McCoy", "Thomas Jay Samuels");

my @sorted_names = sort bylastname @names;

print Dumper \@sorted_names;

sub bylastname
{
    my $lastname_regexp = qr/(\w+)$/;

    my ($a_lastname) = $a =~ $lastname_regexp;
    my ($b_lastname) = $b =~ $lastname_regexp;

    $a_lastname cmp $b_lastname;
}
```

Comment: drmrgd approach above is very nice. It only has to fetch the last name once per array element.

Answer (score 0):

Split each element with the Perl split function. I think you will want something similar to

```
@ary = split(/\s+/, $element);
```

Then grab the last element of `@ary`.

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html

Comment: That's a fairly naive interpretation of what a "last name" is.

Comment: You are probably right.

Comment: And I misread the question anyway, so I blew this one from the beginning. My mistake.

Comment: @friedo True, but almost (?) all less-naive interpretations are likewise wrong, so going with a naive one isn’t all that bad.